# Is it possible to override a file that is loaded by getResourceAsStream when running a jar?

Tags: java, jar, config, getresource

A jar loads a file that is packaged inside the jar itself by using `getResourceAsStream`.

Is it possible to replace/override that file when running `java -jar` without modifying the jar itself?

Comment: Yes, you should look into `ClassLoader` functionality

Comment: What does *replace/override* mean? If it means *writing* to the "file" (which is really a resource and not a file) then the answer is no

Comment: @g00se I mean to replace the file before the jar reads it, so that its behavior can be altered. Not writting to the file that is inside the jar.

Comment: Not possible, but that sounds pretty odd. Why would you need to do that and not just alter it immediately *after* it's been read?

Comment: @g00se it is an external jar that we do not own, and it has a fixed config file packed inside the jar.

Comment: OK. So read it and change the configuration as you wish before it's passed to whatever consumes the config

Answer (score 0):

A jar file just an archive. You could update it with a `jar --update` tool, which is a part of jdk. It may not work if the jar is signed.

Alternatively you could look into (using the `jar` tool) the jar-file to figure out what is a main class (find `Main-Class:` in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`). Then run the jar file specifying classpath explicitly `java -classpath path-with-your-file:theApp.jar`.

Comment: @user85421 Yeah, typo, you are right, fixed.